# Backup apps and their app webs

Tags: list, sharepoint-addin, backup, export, restore

I have an app which has lists in its app web. Is their a way to backup the list and data for the following reasons?

1. Upgrading app.
2. Migrating app.
3. Option to backup and restore list and library items.

Comment: Are you using Office 365 or on premise sharepoint?

Comment: i have an on-premise SharePoint instance

Answer (score 1):

There is the out-of-box solution to provide backup restore on app webs.
Apps are separated from SharePoint, their backup and restore paths are also separate, i.e. you will not manage them from the B/R utilities that SharePoint provides. In most cases, you treat your entire SharePoint environment as a single solution, and so piecemeal restoration is not considered adequate.  You want to restore the entire system from the same point at the same time.  To do this with the App Model,  you need to customize your backup/restore processes to include the Apps.

App data in a SharePoint-Hosted app is not intended to be backed up independently of SharePoint data. If your requirement is to allow that, then you need to create a provider hosted app.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj871017(v=office.15).aspx

[Where and how are sharepoint list stored in sharepoint apps](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89917/where-and-how-are-sharepoint-list-stored-in-sharepoint-apps)